# Ansible lookup file variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to email a template file that has variable in html such as `{{user_name}}`, html renders correctly in my mail client, however `{{user_name}}` doesn't get resolved and displays as string `{{user_name}}`

```
- name: Send e-mail to a bunch of users, attaching files
  mail:
    host: mail.server.com
    subtype: html
    subject: email template
    body: '{{ lookup("file", "roles/binding/templates/email.j2") }}'
    to: "{{ user_email }}"
```

Example output

```
Hi {{ user_name }} ....
```

Desired output

```
Hi John Doe
```

Any ideas on how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a `template` task to process the file, right before the task you have for sending the mail. Example:

```
- name: prepare mail body from template
  template:
    src: email.j2
    dest: /tmp/email.out
```

The variable replacement will take place in this task.

Then, you shall send tha mail with the task you have already prepared, but `body` will have to point to the `/tmp/mail.out` file.

[template module documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html)

Answer (score 3):

Simply replace the `file` lookup plugin with the [`template` lookup plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/lookup/template.html) in the `body` parameter:

```
body: '{{ lookup("template", "roles/binding/templates/email.j2") }}'
```